# What is the difference between a Text instance and string in python?

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

I am trying to use matplotlib module to plot date vs. some values. I'd like to make some changes to the `ticklables` of the `x_axis` and to do that I am using the `xaxis.get_ticklables()`. As the matplotlib Artist tutorial says this function gives a list of `Text` instances. Now the question is, what is a `Text` instance and is there any way I can convert a `Text` instance to strings or numbers?

Thank you.

Comment: Text instance is an object, you can fetch the information of the instance using `<Text instance>.__dict__()`

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: Refer to this link `http://matplotlib.org/users/text_props.html` There is a property called `text`. May be this will help you. The above comment is only valid for getting the useful data of any instance, might not be applicable to your case.

Comment: Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the text, i.e. the string, for all tick labels with:

```
label_texts = [label.get_text() for label in ax.xaxis.get_ticklabels()]
```

A tick label is rich matplotlib object with many ttributes:

```
>>> tick_label = ax.xaxis.get_ticklabels()[0]
>>> len(dir(tick_label))
213
```

Type:

```
>>> dir(tick_label)
```

to see their names.

Comment: I printed out the label_texts but I get the following: [u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'']. I thought I would get the six labels (hopefully with type "string") I was looking for. Am I doing something wrong or I need to add one more layer of conversion here?

Comment: Please  post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), i.e your source code.

Comment: Thanks but I realized I can get what I wanted in a simpler way.